# Bulk Phone number change - DSQUERY

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

I am investigating a way to update the "telephone field" for a large group of users within Active Directory? I would like to match all users with their new phone number as they have moved offices.

I'd like to use DSQUERY/DSMOD to do this but don't know how to match up %username% with the users new phone number which would be in a *.csv file.

Comment: When I run the following dsquery user -samid username "OU=Sale,OU=LONDONSALES,DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com" | dsmod user -tel "8000" -u xxx -p xxx I get the following: dsquery failed:'OU=sales,OU=LONSALES,DC=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=com' is an unknown parameter.
type dsquery /? for help.dsmod failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.

Comment: dsquery user -samid “me” “OU=Systems,OU=Production Services,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=com” | dsmod user -tel “xxxx” -u xxxxx -p xxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dsquery user -samid "me" "OU=Systems,OU=Production Services,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=com" | dsmod user -tel "xxxx" -u xxxxx -p xxxxx
```

Big help [from this blog post](http://blog.crmguru.co.uk/2007/01/01/using-dsmod-to-update-many-active-directory-objects-at-once/#comment-5831).